# SPARQL request excluding individuals with certain types

Tags: sparql

I'm working on a graph where individuals can have any combinations of types from the set {Class1, Class2, Class3, etc.}. Thus, an individual can be of types {Class1, Class 4} or {Class6} or {Class1, Class7}, etc.

I'm trying to write a SPARQL request which gets individuals which:

- have the type Class1
- do not have any of the following types : Class4, Class5, Class6

Here is the request I currently have:

```
  ?s a :Class1.
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s a :Class4}
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s a :Class5}
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s a :Class6}
```

Is there any more elegant way to write it?
For example with `OR` conditions for Class4, Class5 and Class6?
Or with `MINUS`, which I did not really understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data):

```
?s a :Class1 .
FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
   VALUES ?forbiddenClass { :Class4 :Class6 :Class6 }
   ?s a ?forbiddenClass .
}
```